# Codingbat challenge: sumNumbers Stream API Solution

Tags: java, regex, string, java-stream

Given the task [*sumNumbers*](https://codingbat.com/prob/p121193) from *CodingBat*:

> Given a **string**, return the **sum** of the numbers appearing in the string,
> ignoring all other characters. A number is a series of `1` or more digit
> chars in a row.
>
> (Note: `Character.isDigit(char)` tests if `a` char is one
> of the chars `0`, `1`, ..., `9`. `Integer.parseInt(string)` converts `a`
> string to an `int`.)

```
sumNumbers("abc123xyz")  →   123
sumNumbers("aa11b33")    →   44
sumNumbers("7 11")       →   18
```

My solution to this problem is the following:

```
public int sumNumbers(String str) {
  int sum = 0;
  
  java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    }
    
  return sum;
}
```

Is it possible to solve this problem using ***Stream API*** ?

Comment: Just in case, **1.** *Primitive streams* perform better than streams of objects, **2.** usage of collector has an additional cost. That said `sum()` operation on the `IntStream` would be faster than `Collectors.summingInt()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the stream implementation closer to your original solution you could still employ a `Pattern` and `Matcher` and then stream the `Matcher`'s results.

```
public int sumNumbers(String s) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s).results()
        .collect(Collectors.summingInt(m -> Integer.valueOf(m.group())));
}
```

##### Output

```
123
44
18
```

Here is a link to test the code with the expected output:

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/rRS

Answer (score 2):

You maniacs. Just to me snarky you can convert any function to a stream. Map/Reduce is a common pattern:

```
int s = Stream.of("abc123xyz").mapToInt(str->{
    int sum = 0;

    java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    }

    return sum;
}).sum();
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to solve this problem using Stream API?

Split the given string by substring that are not comprised of digits using `.split("\\D+")`. Regex `"\\D+"` matches a string which consists of one or more *non-digit character*. The result will be an array of numeric strings.

Create a stream over the array and filter out strings that are not empty. Then parse the string into `int` with `mapToInt()` and apply `sum()` as a terminal operation.

This solution passes all tests on *CodingBat*:

```
public int sumNumbers(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+"))
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .sum();
}
```

---

Since there could be only a single empty string at the very beginning of the array produced by `.split("\\D+")`, in order to reduce the number of actions performed in the stream-pipeline `filter()` can be replaced with `dropWhile()`.

It will skip the first string if it's *empty*, and after the first *non-empty* element has been encountered this check would not be applied. I.e. *predicate* `dropWhile()` passed to the `dropWhile()` would be executed at most `2` times. In case of lengthy string (*otherwise all optimizations don't matter*) it would be **cheaper** than generating a *new string* with `replaceAll()`.

```
public static int sumNumbers(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+"))
        .dropWhile(String::isEmpty)
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .sum();
}
```

*Caveat:* `dropWhile()` is available with Java 9 onwards. *CodingBat* is still on Java 8, therefore it's unaware of that feature. Nevertheless, it's a valid and also performant solution.
You can test it in your IDE and play around with [*Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rSo)

---

*Tests (the first solution):*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
String[] data = { "abc123xyz", "aa11b33", "7 11" };
```

- `\\D` - Split on any but string of non digits
- filter empty strings from the split
- convert to an `int` and sum the values.
- return an entry to show both string and sum (not needed but shows the association)

```
Arrays.stream(data).map(
        str -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>(
                str,
                Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+"))
                        .filter(s -> !s.isBlank())
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum()))
        .forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%-10s -> %d%n",
                e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

Prints

```
abc123xyz  -> 123
aa11b33    -> 44
7 11       -> 18
```

If you just want the sum you can do the following:

```
public static int getSum(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+"))
                .filter(s -> !s.isBlank())
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .sum();
}
```

Comment: Blank can only occur once and only at the start, so using `str.replaceAll("^\\D+", "").split("\\D+")` would mean you could delete the filter.

Comment: @Bohemian `replaceAll`/`replaceFirst` has to generate a copy of the string, so it doesn't matter that the matching substring would be located at the very beginning. It still needs to iterate over the entire string. There's no need to pay this cost of extra iteration and allocate a new string in memory in order to eliminate redundant invocations of the `filter()`.